# Composer Scheduler is not triggering my DAGs within the planned time

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have the following configuration and the DAG isn't running in the expected time:

```
import pendulum


default_args = {
    "start_date": pendulum.today(),
     "retries": 0,
}

schedule_interval: str = "1 0 * * *"
```

It has been two days the `Next Run: 2022-08-25, 00:01:00` shows the correct day but it is not triggered.

```
Version: 2.2.5+composer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use dynamic `start_date`. This is explained in depth in [Airflow FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#why-is-task-not-getting-scheduled).

Specifically for your case since you are after a daily run, If you want the first DAGRun to start on 2022-08-05 at 01:00 AM then you should set `start_date` as 1 day behind since Airflow trigger runs at the end of the interval:

```
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    "start_date": datetime(2022, 08, 04, 01),
     "retries": 0,
}

dag = DAG(
    ...,
    schedule_interval="1 0 * * *",
    default_args=default_args,

)
```

Note that you can also do:

```
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
     "retries": 0,
}

dag = DAG(
    ...,
    schedule_interval="1 0 * * *",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 08, 04, 01),

)
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the other answer, the problem is with the `start_date` which is always > `run_date`, if you don't want to fix the date for some reasons, you can just replace `pendulum.today()` by `pendulum.yesterday()`.